# How to construct extension message in protobuf.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, protocol-buffers

According to this [post](http://www.indelible.org/ink/protobuf-polymorphism/), I have defined several messages in `Protocol Buffer` format as following

```
message MsgHead
{
    extensions 80 to max;

    enum Type
    {
        REQ = 1;
        RESP = 2;
    }
    required string version = 1;
    required Type type = 2;
}

message Req
{
    extend MsgHead
    {
        required Req msg = 81; // unique message extend number
    }

    optional string id = 1;
    optional string ip_address = 2;
}

message Resp
{
    extend MsgHead
    {
        required Resp msg = 82;
    }

    optional string id = 1;
    optional string time = 2;
}
```

And [`ProtoBuf.js`](https://github.com/dcodeIO/ProtoBuf.js) is used to construct and parse those custom messages.

```
    var req = new Req({
        "id": "60"
        "ip_address": "172.17.67.60"
    });

    var msg_head = new Header();
    msg_head.set("version", '1.0');
    msg_head.set('type', 1);
    msg_head.set('.Req.msg', req);
    // how to construct req message within msg_head?
```

How to construct `Req` message from `MsgHead` directly, just like `req = msg_head.Extensions[Req.msg]`?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from [this](https://github.com/dcodeIO/ProtoBuf.js/wiki/Builder#getters-setters-and-properties)

```
msg_head['.Req.msg']
```

is used to get `Req` message from MsgHead.